# Grounded conductor inside a uniform electric field

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I am working on a textbook problem of a grounded conductor inside a uniform electric field. The textbook states that "grounded" means potential = 0. In my opinion, "grounded" should mean  "same potential as infinity". But in this case we can't set potential at infinity equal zero. So my question is, what is actually the meaning of "grounded". Am I right that it means "equal potential with infinity"? What does it mean by "grounded" in this question when the potential at infinity can't be set to zero?

Comment: Why do you say "we can't set potential at infinity to zero"? The region of uniform electric field must be bounded. And it is created by a pair of equal but opposite charges. Far away the net charge is still zero. Potential at infinity can be trivially set to zero in a universe without net charge. And in any other universe it could be done by convention...

Answer (score 0):

That's only a matter of convention and assumptions. A real ground is always connected to something. In such unbounded systems, a "point of reference" could be charge neutrality. Imagine a huge capacitor that causes the uniform electric field. If the plates of the capacitor had an offset potential (nonzero average potential), it would (as a sum of two single plate capacitors) have a nonzero total charge $e=C_{\text{one plate}}(U_1+U_2)$ with respect to the real infinity where the potential is really zero (just take this statement as an rough illustration). Then you can imagine connecting the inserted conductor to this real infinity outside the oversized capacitor that generates the field.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no right answer here.

There is nothing such as absolute potential and all we have are potential differences between two points. When you say ground potential that could mean any potential in the world.

But I think that when you said that you thought ground should be equal to infinite potential, you meant to say potential at infinite.

I thought so, because if you declare any point as having infinite potential then estimating the potential of any other point with respect to it would be impossible. While if you meant potential at infinite distance, then by the general formula for potential due to point charge 
$$ V = \frac {kq}{r} $$ you'll get 0 potential, again infinite distance is hard to handle but we can work with 0 potential.

Most generally ground/grounding is used in terms of electronics and electrical circuits where it means the conventional potential of earth which is taken as 0.